# A consistent set of axioms

Tags: calculus, logic, propositional-calculus

Let A be a set of axioms, we say that A is nearly consistent is there is a **finite** sub set of A (A') for which A\A' is consistent.

I saw the following 2 claims, and want some help on which direction to go (prove or contradiction):

1. If A and B are nearly consistent then A union B is nearly consistent.
2. If A and B are nearly consistent then A intersection B is nearly consistent.

---

For the first I have did the following trying to prove it and got to dead end:

A is nearly consistent then A\A' is consistent (which means there is a for which a doesn't stem from A\A')

B is nearly consistent then B\B' is consistent (which means there is b for which b doesn't stem from B\B')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim 1 is false, even if $A$ and $B$ are fully consistent. (In fact, we could even have every sentence in $A$ contradict every sentence in $B$.)

In propositional logic we can whip up a very simple example (see the comments below): fixing a set $\{p_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of propositional atoms, let $A=\{p_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{\neg p_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

As an aside, note that as long as we require the sentences involved to be semantically distinct - which is needed to rule out silliness like $A=\{p, p\wedge p, p\wedge (p\wedge p), ...\}$, $B=\{\neg p, \neg p\wedge \neg p, \neg p\wedge(\neg p\wedge \neg p), ...\}$ -  an infinite propositional language is required since there are only $2^{2^n}$ logically distinct propositional sentences in $n$ propositional variables.)

---

The principle also breaks down in first-order logic, and here a finite-language example exists even when we demand semantic distinctness. One way to do this is the following. Take two sentences $\varphi,\psi$ such that each has an infinite model but $\{\varphi,\psi\}$ is inconsistent. Then we can let $$A=\{\varphi\wedge \eta_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\quad\mbox{and}\quad B=\{\psi\wedge\eta_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\},$$ where $\eta_i$ is the sentence "There are at least $i$ many elements in the domain."

Of course you now have to construct such a $\varphi$ and $\psi$, but this is a good exercise. For example, in the language consisting of a single unary relation $U$, we can let

> $\varphi\equiv\exists xU(x)$ and $\psi\equiv\neg\varphi\equiv\forall x\neg U(x)$.

Comment: Isn't there simpler examples, yours seems way more complicated and I believe there is one with finite number of elements like P_0 and not P_0 etc...

Comment: @user128250 There can't possibly be an example with finitely many sentences, since **every** finite set is nearly consistent by definition.

Comment: I think I found simper example, can you take a look, A={P_0, P_1, etc} B={not P_0, not P_1, etc}

Comment: @user128250 That's an example in propositional logic; mine was in first-order logic. Which type of example are you looking for?

Comment: propositional logic

Comment: @user128250 Ah, then yours is the one to go with. (Note that in propositional logic, unlike first-order logic, an infinite language is necessary if we demand that the sentences involved actually be semantically distinct: this is because in propositional logic there are only $2^{2^n}$-many sentences, up to logical equivalence, in a language with $n$ propositional atoms.)

Comment: @user128250 I've edited this into my answer.

Comment: actually my suggestion is wrong as A U B is consistent

Comment: @user128250 What? No it's not. $A\cup B$ contains both (for example) $p_0$ and $\neg p_0$, it's definitely **not** consistent.

Comment: And it's not nearly consistent either: if $X\subseteq A\cup B$ is finite, let $n$ be the greatest index of any propositional atom occurring in an element of $X$. Then $(A\cup B)\setminus X$ contains both $p_n$ and $\neg p_n$ and hence is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, 2 is true. If $A\setminus A^\prime,\,B\setminus B^\prime$ are each consistent, so is their intersection, which contains all elements of $A\cap B$ with the possible exception of those in $A^\prime\cup B^\prime$, i.e. finitely many. This makes $A\cap B$ nearly consistent.

Comment: " so is their intersection" this claim is wrong

Comment: @user128250 No it's not. The intersection of consistent theories is also a susbet of each, so must be consistent, as any contradiction it contained would render one or both of the other theories inconsistent too.

Comment: @user128250 No, J.G. is right. The **intersection** of two consistent theories is always consistent. (Really what's going on is that **any subset of a consistent set is consistent**, and consequently **any subset of a nearly consistent theory is nearly consistent**.)