# Nearly Consistent, is the following true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Continuing [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946271/a-consistent-set-of-axioms):

> Let A be a set of axioms, we say that A is nearly consistent is there
> is a finite sub set of A (A') for which A\A' is consistent.

Is it true to say that:

A is nearly consistent iff each finite sub set of A is  nearly consistent?

Which side is correct and which one isn't?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is essentially contained in the answers/comments to your previous question:

- Using the fact that a subset of a consistent set is consistent, we can easily prove that any subset of a nearly consistent set is nearly consistent. (This is basically the content of J.G.'s answer.) So the left-to-right direction holds.
- In the other direction, in the comments below my answer I mentioned that **every finite set of sentences is nearly consistent** (do you see why?). So no matter what $A$ is, every finite subset of $A$ is nearly consistent. From this it's easy to get a counterexample to the right-to-left direction:

> Just take $A$ to be any set which is not nearly consistent.

(Note that the fact that every finite set is nearly consistent makes my argument in the first bulletpoint unnecessary, but it's still worth understanding.)

Comment: "sing the fact that a subset of a consistent set is consistent, we can easily prove that any subset of a nearly consistent set is nearly consistent" but how? I proved the first one but can't move anymore

Comment: @user128250 Suppose $A$ is nearly consistent and $B\subseteq A$. Since $A$ is nearly consistent there is some finite $F\subseteq A$ such that $A\setminus F$ is consistent; can you find, based on $F$, a finite subset $G\subseteq B$ such that $B\setminus G$ is consistent?

Comment: regarding "do you see why?" I think we can remove the set from itself so we remain with empty set but is an empty set consistent?

Comment: @user128250 The empty set is indeed consistent, but since $B$ might not be finite we can't use $B$ as the desired $G$. You'll need to build $G$ based on $F$.

Comment: @but I mentioned " finite sub"

Comment: @user128250 True, but I thought per your original comment that you were interested in proving the stronger fact that "any subset of a nearly consistent set is nearly consistent." For that you need to do something else.

Comment: got it, but why an empty set is consistent? that doesn't make sense considering the diffenation

Comment: @user128250 Why doesn't it? What does the definition say exactly?